# Getting broken text while reading pdf written in eastern language in python

Tags: python, pdf, unicode, text-extraction, tabula-py

I am facing a problem for while. I am working on a project where I have to make a rest api where it will extract texts from pdf and make json data out of it. The pdf format will be same all time. And I successfully done it by using `tabula-py` but I am getting broken text like this

`"িনবেনর তািরখ` which should be this `নিবন্ধনের তারিক`.

I don't know what is the problem. I tried using different librarys (PyPDF2, pdfminer etc) but getting the same problem. I can't use OCR models because the rest api have to convert pdf to json atleast 400-500 pages on every single request and if I use OCR it will take for ever.

If anyone know how to solve it, Please help me.

I attach my code here I needed :

```
import tabula
import json

# Path to your PDF file
pdf_path = "small.pdf"

# Use Tabula to extract tables from the PDF
tables = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages='all', multiple_tables=True, encoding='sujata')

# Initialize an empty list to store the JSON objects
json_data = []

# Process each table
for table in tables:
    # Convert the table to a JSON string and append it to the list
    json_data.extend(table.to_dict(orient="records"))

# Clean up the dictionary entries
cleaned_data = []
for entry in json_data:
    cleaned_entry = {}
    for key, value in entry.items():
        cleaned_key = key.replace("\r", " ").strip()
        cleaned_value = value.replace("\r", " ").strip() if isinstance(value, str) else value
        cleaned_entry[cleaned_key] = cleaned_value
    cleaned_data.append(cleaned_entry)


def remove_unnamed_keys(data):
    cleaned_data = []
    for entry in data:
        cleaned_entry = {k: v for k, v in entry.items() if not k.startswith("Unnamed") and v is not None}
        cleaned_data.append(cleaned_entry)
    return cleaned_data

cleaned_data = remove_unnamed_keys(cleaned_data)

# Write the cleaned data to output.json file
with open("output.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
    json.dump(cleaned_data, json_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Comment: The first two code points are in different order (`\xe0\xa6\xbf \xe0\xa6\xa8` vs. `\xe0\xa6\xa8 \xe0\xa6\xbf`). You will have to find out it that problem is already present in the PDF. Dome font seem to be able to handle that other don't, so you will have to look at the actual source of the file.

Comment: I make a word file and write some bengali (easter language) text on that and save it as pdf. Then I try to read that and get broken text as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Isn't there any way to fix the problem?